# How to select two column from two different access 2013 database?

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

I have two Database for example "Database1" another is "Database2" whose location at 'Libraries\Documents' at my pc. Now I want to select one column named it "Column3" where another column "ID" of Database1 equal to Database2. So how can I write this query?  And also how can I get those data from different database and same or different location of database? please explain with query example. I found it only for SQL but not for Access database 2013.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have two databases or two _tables_?

Comment: I have one database where I am currently and another database from where I want to get data from one table column.  condition is database1.table1.ID=database2.table2.ID.

Comment: Open database1 , link to database2.table2, write the query in database1.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try link tables from 2nd file into 1st file? 
From one Access DB file you can link tables from various data sources, including all kinds of other databases or excel, csv, xml files, and then you can treat them as "linked table",
for all the local tables and linked tables you can easily join them and build up queries.
It is one of the many handy features that i like to use MS Access for quick and easy tasks.
Hope this helps.